# Получение данных на стороне PHP сервера с внешнего источника по WebSocket с ответом клиенту (приложение на Laravel)

Tags: laravel, websocket

Конфигурация сервер LEMP

Что нужно:

1. Клиент запрашивает информацию.
2. Сервер, получив запрос клиента, отправляет запрос на внешний ресурс через WebSocket (внешний работает только по сокету)
3. Нужно дождаться ответа от внешнего ресурса и обработать ответ.
4. Отправить обработанный ответ клиенту

Пока вижу такой вариант:

1. Подымаю WebSocket-server используя пакет Laravel-Websocket (он будет и как прокси и как обработчик)
2. В нем создаю клиента для внешнего WebSocket
3. Клиенты запросы делают через сокет и сюда же получают ответ

Какие есть еще варианты? Критика, замечания к моему варианту приветствуются

Comment: У Laravel же корявый вебсокет. Он может только отправлять, а принимать от клиента – хрен там. Посмотрите в сторону Swoole вместо PHP-FPM.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar у меня небыло проблем с приемом. Пакеты есть для ларки проверенные (Swoole)?